# What is the importance of a unit vector?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

So obviously, we are all familiar that a unit vector is a vector that has a magnitude of 1 that lies in the same direction as our original vector. But what is the importance of it? Why do we use it? I don't really get the point of it. We can find the magnitude of any vector but what's so important about the unit vector?

I have only seen questions that say "find the unit vector of _i, _j, _k"; however, are there any other applications for unit vector? If so how would we use them?

I am currently a high school student, who is interested to find out more about this interesting concept.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its just useful to represent direction as it doesn't scale. Every vector has a magnitude and a direction. It is often useful to split a vector in to these two components. The direction is the unit vector. So if you are moving at $30$m/s NW then you can think of this as $30$ times a unit vector pointing NW.

Comment: @tomasliam thanks for the reply. That kinda clarifies things. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you an answer which would make a physicist happy. Whenever you measure a physical quantity in certain units, whether its feet, meters, seconds, etc., you can interpret this as choosing a set of unit vectors in a certain space.

Suppose you're measuring a piece of rope. Let's say I want to assign a number and call this the length of the rope. Well to do this, I need to first decide on what it means to be "1". In other words, I need to choose units, or even more down to earth, I need to choose a measuring stick. Say my rope is measured to be 3 feet. Now you can ask, if 3 this inherent, special, God-given number assigned to this rope? No, of course not, because I made a preference towards a specific measuring stick to call "1".

Despite this, we still understand that the length of the rope is a quantity that is somehow intrinsic to this rope. The way to express this is exactly to say that the number we write down changes *against* how the measuring stick changes. For example, I can shrink my measuring stick from feet to inches. If I measured my rope in inches, it would turn out to be 36 inches. Similarly, if I enlarged my measuring stick to yards, I would measure my rope as 1 yard. Thus, it isn't any specific number which specifies the physical quantity known as length, but rather a *transformation law*!

By the way, if generalizing this discussion gives the meme "a tensor is an object which transforms like a tensor".

Answer (score 0):

One reason why unit vectors are important is the following.

Suppose that we have a unit vector $\vec u(t)$ changing with a parameter $t$ (e.g. we may think $t$ as time).

Then we can prove that the derivative $\frac d{dt}\vec u(t)$ (which is a new vector that in some sense measures how $\vec u(t)$ is changing) is actually orthogonal to $\vec u(t)$. This follows immediately taking the derivative both hands of the identity
$$
\vec u(t)\cdot\vec u(t)=1
$$
which describes in terms of the scalar product the fact that the length of $\vec u(t)$ is constantly $1$. In fact the product rule gives
$$
2\frac d{dt}\vec u(t)\cdot\vec u(t)=0.
$$
This fact is actually of some importance when studying curves in space when we take as $\vec u(t)$ a vector tangent to the curve rescaled so to have always length $1$.